# Unable to add parameter to API in swift

Tags: json, swift

I am getting parameter value from other viewcontroller, and i am getting parameter valueperfectly but which i am unable to add to API

here if i hardcode `eventStatus` then its working

and `eventStatus` value from otherviewcontroller also coming perfectly which i am unable to add to API

**if i hard code like this its working**

```
var eventType = "Draft"
let string = Constants.GLOBAL_URL + "/get/allevents/?eventstatus=\(self.eventType)"
```

**Code**: here i am getting correct `eventStatus` value but while breakpoint its control goes to else, why?

```
class EventsViewController: UIViewController {

var eventsListArray = [AnyObject]()
// var eventType = "Draft"
var eventType: String!

var eventList : EventsModel? = nil

@IBOutlet weak var eventsTableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    getAllEventsList()
}

func getAllEventsList() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let headers = ["deviceid": deviceId,"userType": "personal","key": personalId]
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //let string = Constants.GLOBAL_URL + "/get/allevents/?eventstatus=\(self.eventType)"
    let string = Constants.GLOBAL_URL + "/get/allevents"
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: string)

    let eventStatus = self.eventType
        
        print("event status value in API call \(eventStatus)")
    let requestEventType = URLQueryItem(name: "eventstatus", value: eventStatus)

    urlComponents?.queryItems = [requestEventType]
    let urlStr = urlComponents?.url
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: urlStr!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers as! [String : String]
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

        if error == nil {

            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            if httpResponse!.statusCode == 200 {
                do {
                    let jsonObject  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String :Any]
                    print("publish event \(jsonObject)")
                    
                    self.eventList = EventsModel.init(fromDictionary: jsonObject)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    if self.eventList?.events.count != 0 {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.eventsTableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    else {
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            Constants.showAlertView(alertViewTitle: "", Message: "No Events \(self.eventType)", on: self)
                            self.eventList?.events.removeAll()
                            self.eventsTableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
                } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
            } else {
                Constants.showAlertView(alertViewTitle: "", Message: "Something went wrong, Please try again", on: self)
            }
    }
    }
    })
        
    dataTask.resume()
        }
}
}
}
```

where i am wrong, why `eventStatus` value not adding to API.. please suggest me

Comment: `eventType` is never set in the controller so it's `nil`. And your code still contains bad practices like `AnyObject` (replace it with `Any`), `NSMutableURLRequest` (replace it with `var` .. `URLRequest)` and `.mutableLeaves` (delete the `options` parameter).

Comment: @vadian i have changed my code with your suggestions.. and i have given `eventType ` as non optional then also control goes to else part.. where i am mistake

Comment: Once again where do you assign a value to `eventType`? In the code it's declared but not initialized.

Comment: @vadian here `let requestEventType = URLQueryItem(name: "eventstatus", value: eventStatus)`. here `eventStatus` contains `eventType `

Comment: @swiftDev vadian is asking where you are setting the value for `eventType`. Although if you've force unwrapped it should crash.

Comment: Yes but as I said `eventType` is `nil`. It doesn't have a value. Where does the expected `"Draft"` or whatever come from?

Comment: @Frankenstein It doesn't crash because `value` of `URLQueryItem` is optional.

Comment: @vadian Right. So if the value is nil the `URLQueryItem` doesn't get added.

Comment: @Frankenstein oh yeah.. if i give `var eventType = "Published"` its not adding.. what should i do

Comment: @vadian if i give `var eventType = "Published"` then added value not coming in tableview

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have a POST request and you need to use request data instead URL parameters.

[HTTP Request in Swift with POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364914/http-request-in-swift-with-post-method) here you can see:

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
    "eventstatus": yourValue
]
request.httpBody = parameters.percentEncoded()
```

You also need to create parameters with **eventStatus**. And put it in

```
request.httpBody = parameters.percentEncoded()
```

If this endpoint on your server waits on this data in request body than you could not add it like a URL parameter.

Also, don't forget these 2 extensions from the example

```
extension Dictionary {
    func percentEncoded() -> Data? {
        return map { key, value in
            let escapedKey = "\(key)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed) ?? ""
            let escapedValue = "\(value)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed) ?? ""
            return escapedKey + "=" + escapedValue
        }
        .joined(separator: "&")
        .data(using: .utf8)
    }
}

extension CharacterSet { 
    static let urlQueryValueAllowed: CharacterSet = {
        let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@" // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
        let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="

        var allowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
        allowed.remove(charactersIn: "\(generalDelimitersToEncode)\(subDelimitersToEncode)")
        return allowed
    }()
}
```

Comment: You don't need to encode parameters in an HTTP body because it's not part of the URL and on the other hand `URLComponents` **does** add the percent encoding.

Comment: You are right. It is a reference to post above, here we need to put data in httpBody in Data Type.

Answer (score 0):

The solution must be obvious from the discussion in the comments. Although you seem a little puzzled so, I'm adding this to help you out. The value of `eventType` is never getting allocated to a value, it is remaining as `nil` unless you set it's value at a point in your code before the API call. So here is a way for you to figure this out:

```
let string = "https://www.google.com" + "/get/allevents"
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: string)

let eventStatus = self.eventType ?? "Published" // here value is defaulted to "Published"
let requestEventType = URLQueryItem(name: "eventstatus", value: eventStatus)

urlComponents?.queryItems = [requestEventType]
let urlStr = urlComponents?.url
print(urlStr?.absoluteString)
```

Here, we're setting a default value for `eventType` for the scenario where `eventType` is `nil`.